# What is the `.arr` function in this piece of code?

Tags: c

I am coming from Python, but I have seen this code in Codefights for the C language and I cannot find with google what `.arr` means. I don't see there is any variable in the code either:

```
// Definition for arrays:
// typedef struct arr_##name {
//   int size;
//   type *arr;
// } arr_##name;
//
// arr_##name alloc_arr_##name(int len) {
//   arr_##name a = {len, len > 0 ? malloc(sizeof(type) * len) : NULL};
//   return a;
// }
//
//

int firstDuplicate(arr_integer a) {
    int i = 0;
    int val = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < a.size; i++) {
        val = a.arr[i];
        if(val < 0) {
            val = -1*val;
        }
        if(a.arr[val-1] < 0) {
            return val;
        } else {
            a.arr[val-1] = a.arr[val-1]*-1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Is `a.arr[i]` the same `as a[i]`?

Comment: Show us definition of `arr_integer`.

Comment: `.` is structure member access operator, read about it.

Comment: No, 'arr_integer` is a `structure`. You are trying to access an element in the structure, using the `.`. `arr` is an array which is an element in the structure.

Comment: `arr` is something that is defined on the `arr_integer` type - it's not intrinsic to C.

Comment: I added the arr_integer definition. I thought it was just a comment lol

Comment: There's presumably a macro that is used to define a type named `arr_integer`.  And that type is a `struct` which has a member named `arr`.   In your code, `a` is a variable of type `arr_integer`, and `a.arr` obtains the member of `a` named `arr`.   You won't find anything with google, since this is specific code that you have (or have been given by someone else).

Comment: I'm one of those still not accustomed to struct initializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a method, there is no such thing in C. It is a [structure member](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_structures.htm).

My guess is that before your code sample, there is a definition of `arr_integer` as:

```
typedef struct {
    int *arr;
    // Other members
} arr_integer;
```

or

```
typedef struct {
    // Other members
    int arr[];
} arr_integer;
```

The *Other members* being probably the array's size and capacity.

Comment: I have added the definition what I thought just to be comments (facepalm).
does the *arr in the definition mean that is of type pointer of array? and when it calls .arr[i] is looking for the address in memory?

Comment: `int *arr` means a pointer to integer values. `arr[i]` means access to the `i`th element if the pointer, i.e. the element at address `arr + i`. It is the same operation than with arrays.

Answer (score 2):

If I am not mistaken, in CodeFights you work with a wrapper defined as:

```
// Definition for arrays:
typedef struct arr_##name {
   int size;
   type *arr;
} arr_##name;
```

Thus, `arr_integer` is not an array, but a `struct` that holds an array of int. To access its elements, you need the `.arr`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Derlin above.
Here is a piece of code to print out your elements

```
arr_arr_integer rotateImage(arr_arr_integer a) {
    int i=0, j=0;

    for(i=0; i<a.size;i++){
        for(j=0; j<a.size;j++){
            printf("i=%d, j=%d, %d\n",i,j,a.arr[i].arr[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Like pointed out, the structure definition would look something like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int size;
    int arr[];
} arr_integer;

typedef struct {
    int size;
    arr_integer arr[];  
} arr_arr_integer;
```